# How to make last item in Row always visible?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm wondering how I can easily always display the icon right after the text, even when there is not enough space, I want to display the icon and break the text into two lines. Any ideas?

```
Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(180.dp)
                    //.width(50.dp)
                    .height(50.dp)
                    .background(Color.LightGray)
            ) {
                Row(
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "lorem ipsum",
                        maxLines = 2,
                        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                    )

                    Icon(
                        Icons.Default.AccountBox,
                        tint = Color.Black,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(8.dp)
                            .size(24.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want to break lorem ipsue into two lines, with icons to appear to both at the end of each word ?

Comment: Only one icon for whole row

Comment: If you want to break it then you have to give it fix width to the text. Can you explain more what is your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `.weight()` modifier in `Row` item:

```
Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically, horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start) {
    Text(
        text = "lorem ipsum",
        maxLines = 2,
        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)    // This will do the trick for you
    )

    Icon(
        imageVector = Icons.Default.AccountBox,
        contentDescription = "Account Box",
        modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)
    )
}
```

Comment: But the icon is at the end of Box when there is a lot of space. I want to display icon always next to text.

Comment: As answered by @jan-itor , you need to set `fill = false` in `weight` modifier

Answer (score 1):

Add `weight` modifier with `fill` set to false to the `Text`. When `fill` is false, the element is not forced to take all the available space so the `Icon` will remain right next to it.

```
.weight(weight = 1f, fill = false)
```

Answer (score 0):

A Composable called BoxWithConstraints can help you. The BoxWithConstraints permit you to query it's measures in it's scope such as maxWidth, by means of which it is possible count the maximum width of the composable show texts 'lorem ipsum'.

```
    BoxWithConstraints {
    val max = this.maxWidth - 24.dp

    Text(text = "lorem ipsum", modifier = Modifier.widthIn(max = max))

}
```

Comment: The maximum width of the composable that shows texts 'lorem ipsum'  is always less than its parent's. So, there is always space for others.